Is there any method like GetAllActorsOfClass() in Unreal5 but only get all actors inside a certain range?
So currently I'm using unreal5 and c++ to develop a game, and I want to shot a ball and this ball will be able to affect all actors inside certain range.
But since inside the level we have a huge number of actors, it may cause some performance issue to detect the distance betweeen the ball and each object. So I'm thinking if there is a way to fast skip some objects who are not inside the range?

Create an Actor with an overlapping area that has the area you want to cover and call AActor::GetOverlappingActors(). It will return an array of contained ie. overlapped actors not including itself. You could do this on your projectile actor by adding a volume|collider shape to it.

Oh thanks for answering, I will try this way and see if it can match my requirement!
